# How to convert java.time.Duration to java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, time

What is the best way to convert a `java.time.Duration`-object to `java.sql.Time`?

I am getting an ISO8601-String like `PT15M51S` and `Duration.parse(String s)` is quite suitable in this case.

But now I'm struggling how to get the `java.sql.Time` to but it into `PreparedStatement` with `setTime(java.sql.Time time)` to store it in my MySQL-database using JDBC.

I ended up writing a tapeworm like from `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DurationFormatUtils`:

```
java.sql.Time.valueOf(DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(video.getDuration().toMillis())))
```

And for the next problem: How to get `java.time.Duration` from a `java.sql.Time`.

Answer (score 3):

A `java.sql.Time` is **not** a duration, it is a time within a day (ie the normal 24 hour clock). Storing a duration in it is a hack and that hack will break if that duration is longer than 24 hours. You are better off storing it as the ISO duration string, or in a number datatype (eg double, or maybe numeric) or if your database supports it: in an `interval`.

However if you still want to store the duration in a sql `TIME`: The conversion point from `java.time` to `java.sql.Time` is `java.time.LocalTime` using [`java.sql.Time.valueOf(LocalTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-). So to convert from a `Duration` to `java.sql.Time` you can do:

```
Duration duration = ..;
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(duration);
java.sql.Time sqlTime = java.sql.Time.valueOf(localTime);
```

The conversion back would be:

```
java.sql.Time sqlTime = ..;
LocalTime localTime = sqlTime.toLocalTime();
Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, localTime);
```

Be aware that a `java.sql.Time` might only have precision in seconds. With a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver conversion to `java.sql.Time` is not necessary because storing a `java.time.LocalTime` is supported directly using `setObject(1, <your LocalTime>)` and `getObject(1, java.time.LocalTime.class)`.

Comment: Although I agree that it's not preferred to store duration in a `TIME` column, it will not break on durations longer than 24 hours. I updated my answer with a link to the corresponding section of the MySQL documentation...

Comment: @dpr Interesting, I did not know that about `TIME` in MySQL. However, I don't think that would be fully supported through `java.sql.Time`.

Comment: it seems to be - don't know if it is officially supported though. One can create arbitrary long `java.sql.Time` instances by using the Constructor `Time(long)`. However I'm not sure what it looks like when it comes to support of other DBMS'...

Answer (score 1):

Is the database structure fixed? I think `TIME` or `TIMESTAMP` is probably not the best data type for duration. I would change the column type to `BIGINT` (aka `Long`) and convert the duration to milliseconds (or nanoseconds depending on your needs) with `Duration.toMillis()`.

If this is not an option, you could use a similar logic and represent the duration as offset from a certain timestamp, such as `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` with `Duration.addTo(referenceDate)` or `java.sql.Time(durationInMillis)`. To obtain an instance of `Duration` again you will need to use `Duration.ofMillis(sqlTime.getTime())`.

These are basically the options you have:

Using `BIGINT` as column type (preferred solution):

```
// from java.time.Duration to java.lang.Long
{
    final Duration duration = ...
    final PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement("...");
    pStmnt.setLong(n, duration.toMillis());
}

// from java.lang.Long to java.time.Duration
{
    final PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement("...");
    final ResultSet resultSet = pStmnt.getResultSet();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        final Long durationInMillis = resultSet.getLong(n);
        final Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(durationInMillis);
        ...
    }
}
```

Using `TIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as column type. You can replace `java.sql.Time` with `java.sql.Timestamp` in the below code depending on your actual column type:

```
// from java.time.Duration to java.sql.Time(stamp)
{
    final Duration duration = ...
    final Time time = new Time(duration.toMillis());

    final PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement("...");
    pStmnt.setTime(n, time);
}

// from java.sql.Time(stamp) to java.time.Duration
{
    final PreparedStatement pStmnt = con.prepareStatement("...");
    final ResultSet resultSet = pStmnt.getResultSet();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        final Time time = resultSet.getTime(n);
        final Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(time.getTime());
        ...
    }
}
```

According to MySQL's documentation the `TIME` type supports ranges from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)). But by default none of the types `TIME`, `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` support fractional seconds unless the desired precision has been specified at creation time of the database columns (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)). That is to store milliseconds in a `TIME` column, the table needs to be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3));
```

---

**Update:**

- Added more detailed code examples
- Added link to MySQL documentation regarding the supported min max values for `TIME`